# BroadcastReceiver does not receive intent Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want my app to be aware anytime the user changes the locale. So in my `Application` class, I create a `receiver` to listen to the system intent `ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED`:

```
public final class MyApp extends Application {

    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String locale = Locale.getDefault().getCountry();
        Toast.makeText(context, "LOCALE CHANGED to " + locale, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    };

    @Override public void onCreate() {
       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED);

       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
    }
}
```

When I press home and go to the settings app to change my locale, the Toast is not shown.  Setting the breakpoint inside `onReceive` shows it never gets hit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED` is not a local broadcast, so it won't work when you register it with `LocalBroadcastManager`. `LocalBroadcastManager` is used for the broadcast used inside your app.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String locale = Locale.getDefault().getCountry();
        Toast.makeText(context, "LOCALE CHANGED to " + locale,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
}

}
```

Comment: thanks, why doesnt getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString() inside onReceive reflect this new locale?

Comment: @user3148156 the new locale can be get like this `context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale` inside the `onReceive` method.

Answer (score 14):

Why do you want the BroadcastReceiver in Application class. My suggestion is to have a separate class for BroadcastRecevier.

```
public class LocaleChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        if (intent.getAction (). compareTo (Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED) == 0)
        {

            Log.v("LocaleChangedRecevier", "received ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED");
        }

    }
}
```

and register your Brodcast receiver in Manifest file.

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".LocaleChangedReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: works for me on Android O. but it takes up to 8 seconds to get it.
IMHO To long for a UI change

Comment: For me, Not working this