LOCALE_CHANGED receiver called with null extras every time
Each time i change the language in settings LOCALE_CHANGED action broadcast receiver onReceiver method callback comes with null extras. I want th language code which is changed in settings.
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.widget.Toast

class VzLocaleReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

      override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

           Toast.makeText(
                          context,
                          "language changed ${intent?.extras}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                          ).show()
  }

}
<receiver
        android:name=".utils.VzLocaleReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


Please refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30448393/10970789

Thanks @SachinHarne, I need System default locale but it returns App locale, eg: if we set the App Language to "fr" and then in side system setting we change it to "en". then  if we try to Locale.getDefault().getCountry() it will return the "fr".
